# Making an ice cream or icing effect as shown in GIF below

Tags: unity, graphic-effects, fluid-dynamics

How can I make an effect like filling a cone with soft serve ice cream, or putting icing on a cake. I want to have the real icing effect shown in the https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/1248475917975867392?s=19 link.
In the game play scene there will be three buttons with different ice cream colors at the bottom, one icing machine at the top with three colors same of the buttons and an image displayed that is to be matched on the left corner.If a user press the yellow button the ice cream starts popping out from the yellow part of the machine and and if blue button is pressed blue cream start's popping out and vice versa.The machine will fill up the cone in a circular manner. When the button is pressed the machine starts animating in a circular manner on top of the cone and if the user stops in between and than start again than the icing machine should start from the same position where it left. A bar on the top will show the complete percentage of the filling cone
[image: Game scenario]
When the cup or cone is filled and the level processing bar is completed than it will be checked at the end and given points according to the matched percentage.Like if the prepared cone matches 100 percent with the matched image than it will be given full points and if the color of the layers doesn't match properly than points will be deducted according to the matching criteria.
[image: Level completed]

[image: Example of ice cream effect]
([Animated example via this article](https://soyummy.com/jump-summer-4-fun-frozen-treats/))

Comment: I think the keyword you are looking for is "fluid simulation" (soft ice cream behaves like a fluid with a high viscosity and low density). If you intend to program this yourself, you have a lot of work ahead of you. But there are various existing solutions available on the asset store.

Comment: I've added an example image to your question: can you confirm that's the style of effect you're looking for? As you can see, the classic helix of soft serve involves some coordinated movement of either the cone or dispenser or both. Can you tell us a bit about how this will be implemented in your game? Are these objects free to move due to physics or player input, so we have to simulate how the material gets pulled along? Or can we strictly control their motion with an exactly repeatable animation, letting us take shortcuts?

Comment: Soft serve ice cream could be simulated similarly to rope physics:

https://youtu.be/Cecp4a7FsTU?t=556

Comment: yes @DMGregory  this is the effect i want to make .. Like i have a pastry or biscuits and i want to do icing on them same like in the figure.Can you please guide me more with this

Comment: Please answer the questions at the end of my previous comment.

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry but i dont find here any option to answer a specific person.Like i have told u i need the same thing as u have shown in the figure above.Help please

Comment: I'm asking you to answer this: "Can you tell us a bit about how this will be implemented in your game? Are these objects free to move due to physics or player input, so we have to simulate how the material gets pulled along? Or can we strictly control their motion with an exactly repeatable animation, letting us take shortcuts?"

Comment: Thankyou for your concern @DMGregory. I am sending u a reference video. When we tap on screen it will start topping our object with cream like this  shown in video. Please have a look. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YF7ETV7Om0

Comment: That's a very different effect than what's shown in the gif above. Based on your earlier comment saying the gif was the effect you needed, [I started working on a shader to make a helical cone of icing](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/1248475917975867392?s=19), but if what you actually want is a continuous log of icing laid down in a line, that would be approached differently. Please edit your question to ensure what you actually need is clear — explain as much as you can about your application, or use images/screenshots/diagrams/animations to show what you need.