# How to Procedurally generate a mesh with animation for Creamy Effect in Unity (mobile supported)

Tags: unity, procedural-generation

[I want this cream effect in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4R5BLzR6fg)

I have checked OBI Fluid which seems to be the best fluid simulation pack so far in Unity but I am not sure if I really need that for this scope. Maybe vertex shaders? Any suggestions on how this reference mechanics would've been implemented and how I can re-create it as I am in love with that creamy feeling.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any physics/fluid simulation happening here at all, just an animation of a procedural mesh, with a parameter for the elevation.

Comment: Yes, you right and now after your comment, I can make sense that I was incorrect in thinking that it was sort of physics simulation but can you point me in a direction of how I can achieve this? There are multiple materials for creating procedural planets, cube, terrain but not the complex shapes with animations or that I haven't found one. I am not an expert in this so I apologize if I didn't get the complete idea with your above comment.

Comment: I have also changed the title as I thought it was misleading/incorrect for future viewers to see.

Comment: You won't be able to find a super-specialized tutorial for *everything* you want to do. At some point you need to come up with your own solutions to problems. Try to find out how procedural mesh generation works in general by following any procedural mesh generation tutorial, and then see how you can apply that knowledge to solve the problem you want to solve.

Comment: @Philipp yes you are right that I won't get the super-specialized tutorial and I am not asking for an exact code or any such thing at all. I am asking is that you or many experienced persons out there who could point me in a better direction. Yes I am learning procedural mesh generation and I am following few tutorials including live stream sessions like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xs0Saff940 but again the person who knows how to do it will exactly know which things I have to get a grasp of in order to achieve this. Yes it's ambitious but em aiming there and eventually, I'll be there.

Comment: @DMGregory how about spline-based mesh extrusion or generation? Using Cap for that smooth look?

Comment: @SyedMunimRaza Pretty sure its just a vertex animation of mesh from small to longest it can get, and in script you will play it from 0 to the timestamp you need to. it also has just a few bones to simulate physics of touching other objects. With a little bit of hard work this is achievable even with basic knowledge of 3d.

Comment: @Nick a very interesting solution but I have a question about the length. Like yes, you can animate vertex but what about this endless cream length? It depends on when the user stops pressing so its variable to almost as long as one wants. Is that achievable through just a vertex animation?

Comment: @SyedMunimRaza its not endless from the video I've seen, it most probably does have maximum length since there are these "Knives" or whatever coming every N distance. So exactly that N distance will be length of the whole animated mesh. If you want an endless one you can break your cream into 3 parts, start, middle and end, and for example make the middle one seamless from 2 sides so that you can spawn them one after the other or something.

Comment: @DMGregory I saw a post and followed you on twitter where you had work in progress related to this post. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/181537/making-an-ice-cream-or-icing-effect-as-shown-in-gif-below
I was curious that how you did it.